# Edge detection circuit (for rotary encoder)

Tags: logic-gates, interrupts, signal-processing

I managed to decode a rotary encoder using an arduino to read the input signal but I noticed other than the interrupts, the code is mainly made up of lines similar to: "IF this AND that OR that AND that" which can be easily implemented using 74LS logic chips.

So I decided to make a circuit to do that, but I need to design something to detect the rising/falling edge of each signal. I did a bit of research but most of the recommended circuits are fairly complex so they can't be easily implemented.

Someone recommended using not gates and taking advantage of their gate delays to detect the edge but I can't come up with a good idea. If anyone has a circuit suggestion that can be easily implemented on a small PCB, I would love to hear their idea.

EDIT:
I'm using a 600 Pulse per revolution optical encoder so it is noise free. It's quadrupled in software to get an effective 2400 pulses per revolution.

> **I DO NOT WANT TO USE AN ARDUINO FOR READING THE SIGNAL. it is easily**
>   **overloaded in my application.**

Comment: Have you searched yet

Comment: If you have bounce suppression caps your code can be as simple as one XOR expression, or as "complex" as 3 IFs. It is about the same as you need to process externally decoded direction

Comment: Please explain why you would want to do this so that we can better understand your goal for this project.  Encoder handling can be quite efficient in a uC.  Perhaps you have a reason to move it off?

Comment: Do you just want to make an up/down counter with the encoder feeding the counter?

Comment: Some Arduinos have interrupt on CHANGE feature that might let the micro hardware to the hard work for you if you are happy to code an interrupt routine.  Such an interrupt driven encoder routine might already exist.

Comment: I'm trying to get the arduino to read a 600 Pulse per revolution encoder with quadrupled pulsing (effective 2400 Pulse per revolution) and use it as an accurate RPM calculator. The motor spins 1500 to 10000 RPM so arduino effectively becomes useless if it's reading interrupts that often. Believe me, I tested it :/ I'm just looking for an edge detecting circuit so please don't spam the comments with various ways of using the micro controller. Thanks

Comment: (1) Your question says nothing about using the encoder as a tachometer (RPM calculator) and this is critical to the solution. (2) You will need a counter and timer, a latch and a display. You'll need to edit your question again and add some sort of specification for your requirements. (3) This should include the fact that you don't require direction information (which would normally be required in an encoder application). 10000 RPM x 2400 pulses = 400,000 counts/s. (4) What is your required accuracy? (5) What is your preferred logic family?

Comment: @OM222O You skipped the most essential part of the question, what did you expect the answers would be? Now, the edge detecting circuit will cut the interruptions only by half. Are you sure it is enough to take load of your software?

Comment: First, you need to explain what you want the output of this circuit to be.  Is it supposed to be a parallel binary value from 0 to 2399?  Is it supposed to calculate speed directly?  If so, how is it supposed to present that value to the micro?  Second, you need to separate requirements from implementation.  A requirement may be to offload position tracking from your micro, but that shouldn't state *how* that is to be accomplished.  With the right requirements, you don't care how it's done if they are met.  Using 74LS chips is implementation, not requirement.

Comment: https://circuitelec.blogspot.com/2009/03/rotary-encoder-circuit.html?m=1 thought this will be useful

Comment: You say the encoder produces 600 full cycles/revolution.  But, what is the fastest revolution rate you need to support?

Comment: @OlinLathrop it's in comments, not in question :/  10000 RPM

Comment: @Map: That means it's not really there at all.  Comments aren't for content.  No, I'm not going to wade thru a long comment chain to get pertinent information about the question.

Comment: @OM222O: You have edited your question again but failed to address the points raised in the comments regarding various specifications and clarifications required in your question. You are shouting at us that you don't want to use an Arduino but the previous sentence says that the encoder resolution is quadrupled in software. Your requested hardware-only solution doesn't have software. Can you see how your question is not answerable and is likely to be closed as "unclear what you are asking"?

Comment: @Transistor The signal is quadrupled in software by checking the change in each signal (using both rising and falling edges ). That is exactly why I want a edge detection circuit. The rest of the circuit is already built and doesn't need any spec.

Comment: Sorry, but you are refusing to realise from all the comments that your question is far from clear. I am giving up and voting to close as "unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using a 600 Pulse per revolution optical encoder so it is noise free

If your encoder is noise free then you don't need "edge detection circuit", the interrupt pin already does that.

> I'm trying to get the arduino to read a 600 Pulse per revolution encoder with quadrupled pulsing (effective 2400 Pulse per revolution) and use it as an accurate RPM calculator. The motor spins 1500 to 10000 RPM

if you don't need a direction, only RPM then:

- you can use only **one** output channel of the encoder, cutting the interrupts in half.
- you can program interrupt pin to detect only **one** edge of the signal, either rising or falling, cutting interrupts in half again.
- if that is still too fast for your code you can use Counter or D-trigger chips to divide the frequency to any acceptable range. Cost-wise it is the same as 74LS gate logic but with simplicity of using a single IC.

Comment: I am trying to do it using HARDWARE. I've explained it over and over, just read the question ...

Comment: **"I'm trying to get the arduino to read ..."** make up you mind and edit your question. Where the output of that hypothetical hardware will go and in what format? You don't make any sense now.

Comment: I've already built everything else, the outputs are handled the way they should be. I just need an edge detection circuit to analyze signals A and B on both rising and falling edges. This is a pretty simple question to understand.

Comment: That is gibberish. What is "analyze signals"? Measure slew rate? Measure amplitude? **What are you connecting "edge detection circuit" to?** What output from it do you expect? You refusing to answer simple questions and expecting people to give you advice without knowing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This would be for step up/down outputs

With suitable noise suppression...

[timing / schematic](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/aug/~/media/Images/Article%20Library/TechZone%20Articles/2012/August/Motion%20Sensing%20Via%20Rotary%20Shaft%20Encoders%20Assures%20Safety%20and%20Control/article-2012august-motion-sensing-via-rotary-shaft-encoders-fig4.jpg)

Edge detection in hardware is simply XOR’ ing the input with a small time delay.

In software it is the same.

- sample input, save Sample XOR both results for a change.   Then input level (if noise free) plus transition detect determines direction of edge.  Thus input frequency max and noise free are requirements to determine max sample interval delay.

Comment: ... which would make no sense whatsoever, since those outputs will go into the same arduino

Comment: It makes sense if you know how to code an up/down counter by If last state =0 and present state Up =1 increment counter