# Edge detection circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, signal-processing

I need to design an edge detection circuit to detect when a square wave signal goes from Low to High (rising edge) and when it goes from High to Low (falling edge). The circuit should preferably use simple logic control such as 74LS series logic. I know people are gonna suggest using an arduino with interrupts but in my application this needs to be done in hardware rather than software.

Edit: The output is expected to be a short digital pulse, used as a trigger.

Comment: A resistor, a capacitor, and an xor gate should do the trick.

Comment: Did you ever bother to google for {edge detection with logic} ? Or Stack Exchange at least? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/270894/117785 I know it is not nice, but really?

Comment: @AliChen, no, it is actually a second attempt to ask the same question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/382104

Comment: @Maple, this is the second attempt by OP, true. But exactly this question was asked years ago and has perfect answers.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Ll8K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: the circuit looks good, but also explain the working. like if the input contains a clock how does the output change as the clock rises, stays positive and then falls.

Answer (score 0):

A simple differentiator circuit should do what you ask(the pulse will be fairly short but enough to trigger a bistable multivibrator or something). Read more at https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_7.html:
[image]

Comment: Your circuit produces negative spike on falling edge. I suspect it is not what OP wants even though he refuses to tell what he's connecting edge detecting circuit to.

Comment: Wouldn't the negative spike be on the rising edge?

Comment: He can add a diode if he doesn't want the negative edge.